# Find last number in a text file

Tags: batch-file, find

I have a text file that looks a bit like this:

```
SometextSometextSometext
Sometext
5
6
3
5
78
15
SometextSometext
Sometext
```

the last nuber can change its value and location (more numbers can be added or subtracted)

I need to find that last number
please help
thank you
shabi

Comment: A simple way is read the file line by line and then word by word. Do this in reverse way using Random file access.

Comment: What should be found if the last line is `Freddy34Frog`? 34 or 15?

Comment: thanks for the quick response, i need to find the number 15 in this example. what does it mean to search "line by line and then word by word"?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in ('findstr /b /e /r "[0-9]*" tst.txt') do set "last_num=%%a"
```

replace tst.txt with the path to your text file.This will save the last number to 
%last_num% variable.